# php query Select 10 players and 3 reserves for each one

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, multiple-select

table players

player1

player2

player3

player4

player5

...

player100

etc

I need to select 10 unique random teams with 4 players as: 1 base and 3 pivots

Currently trying to use:

```
    require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10"; 
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
    $i =1;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) { 
        echo "$i Base  = ";
        echo $row['id'];
        echo "<br />";  
        echo 'Pivot';   
        echo "<br />";
        if ($i % 4 == 0)
     {
       echo '<br />';
     }
     $i++;
    } 
    mysql_close();
```

Result must be:

```
**team 1**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3

**team 2**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3

**team 3**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3

**team 4**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3

**team 5**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3

**team 6**
Base 1
Pivot 1
Pivot 2
Pivot 3
```

Comment: Maybe just select 40 (10*4) users and then take one by one and first is base, next three are pivots, and again base and then pivots...

Comment: Important rule! First we need to extract 10 base! After that we must select 3 pivot for every team/base

Comment: Why is that? Why should that matter for the machine? Everything needs to be random, right?

Comment: Yes! Everything need to be random and unique! Each selected base or pivot can not be in another team! BASE position is a prize! I need to extract first 10 base and after that three pivots for each one

Comment: What's 'first' when you `ORDER BY RAND()`? Every player in the result is equally randomly positioned.

Comment: That's the point! How i can get unique random 10 base (first) with unique random 3 pivots for selected base?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you execute multiple queries for this, teams may overlap. It all needs to be done in a *single query* that selects 40 random players and then distribute them to the teams:

```
$nteams=$_POST['teams']; 
$nbase=$_POST['base'];
$npivots=$_POST['pivots']; 
$allplayers=$nteams*($nbase+$npivots);
require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
$sqlCommand = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $allplayers";
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
if(mysql_num_rows($query)<$allplayers) // sanity
  die('Not enough players!');
else
  for($team=1;$team<=$nteams;$team++)
    {
    for($base=1;$base<=$nbase;$base++)
      {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      echo "Team $team Base $base = {$row['id']}<br />";
      }
    for($pivot=1;$pivot<=$npivots;$pivot++)
      {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
      echo "Team $team Pivot $pivot  = {$row['id']}<br />";
      }
    }
mysql_close();
```

**EDIT**: Changed the code to parametrize the number of teams,base players and pivots as per your comments.

Comment: you made my day! Best regards... you deserve a beer... EUREKA, hug you....kiss you :-) thanks dude

Comment: Some extra isue! Because i have over 200 players i need to be able to input LIMIT value and PIVOT value as: $teams = $_POST['teams'];
$base = $_POST['base']; $pivots = $_POST['pivots']; Can u help me?

Comment: @custombrands You want the number of teams and the number of players to be parametrized?

Comment: Yes! I want to input base numbers and pivots number!

Comment: sometime i have few players and every team will have 3 players (1 base & 2 pivots). I think is better if i will use a form with get value!

Comment: I use it but... because i don't know the number of players who sign up i think is better to input only the number of bases and pivots for querry. i was trying to remove teams parameter but... stackoverflow!

Comment: so...if i enter only bases and pivots i will have generate all team possible from all players who sign up else i will get Not enough players!

Comment: This is turning into a discussion, and SO is not meant to be a forum. Consider posting your new concerns as a new question, to give others the opportunity to answer too. I'll be happy to contribute as well.

Comment: I just post new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19788210/select-random-teams-of-players-base-and-pivots

Answer (score 0):

This simple code should work :

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    if($i % 4 == 0) 
        echo "<BR /> Base  = " . $row['id'];
    else 
        echo " Pivot : ". $row['id'];
    $i++;
}
```

Greg

Comment: I was trying but give me 10 players not 10 team!

Comment: @Greg the result si 
Base = 11 Pivot : 12 Pivot : 9 Pivot : 6
Base = 10 Pivot : 7 Pivot : 5 Pivot : 8
Base = 13 Pivot : 4