# Select random teams of players (base and pivots)

Tags: sql, algorithm, sorting, multiple-select

I have a table players with N users who sing up!
I need to create random unique team from that list!

Great to @geomagas currently i use:

```
    $nteams=$_POST['teams']; 
    $nbase=$_POST['base'];
    $npivots=$_POST['pivots']; 
    $allplayers=$nteams*($nbase+$npivots);
    require_once "connect_to_mysql.php"; 
    $sqlCommand = "SELECT id FROM players ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $allplayers";
    $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
    if(mysql_num_rows($query)<$allplayers) // sanity
      die('Not enough players!');
    else
      for($team=1;$team<=$nteams;$team++)
        {
        for($base=1;$base<=$nbase;$base++)
          {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
          echo "Team $team Base $base = {$row['id']}<br />";
          }
        for($pivot=1;$pivot<=$npivots;$pivot++)
          {
          $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
          echo "Team $team Pivot $pivot  = {$row['id']}<br />";
          }
        }
    mysql_close();
```

I thought initially to generate the number of teams but I realized that it might not have a huge number of players. If at first wanted to be able to set/input the number of teams, bases and pivots now I want to enter only the number of bases and pivots to generate teams.
Example: I will input 3 bases with 2 pivots and the result should be:

**team 1**
base 1
pivot 1
pivot 2

**team 2**
base 1
pivot 1
pivot 2

**team 3**
base 1
pivot 1
pivot 2

Every selected base and pivots must be unique in order to generate different teams!

Comment: Please be sure to **explicitly** state what you want from us in the form of a question.

Comment: I need to eliminate teams value from code above and from html form to input only base and pivots value! when i input 3 base with 2 pivot must be generated 3 teams! One team means 1 base (player) + 2 pivots (players)

Comment: So why not just set `$nteams=3;` instead of `$nteams=$_POST['teams'];`?